# Looking for nexus api command showing aritifact details

Tags: api, nexus

Does anyone know what api command I can run which details the artifact details in Sonatype Nexus?

In the Nexus browser, I see two tabs then I go into my repository, Maven and Artifact.

I can use the lucene search api to extract information from the Maven tab, but I cant seem to find the api command which details the Artifact tab.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this article by us at Sonatype to learn the REST API call you need to use:

http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2015/01/26/learn-the-nexus-rest-api-automating-sonatype-nexus/